# iOS touch coordinate system

Tags: ios

> - locationInView: Returns the current location of the receiver in the coordinate system of the given view.
>
> This method returns the current location of a UITouch object in the
>   coordinate system of the specified view. Because the touch object
>   might have been forwarded to a view from another view, this method
>   performs any necessary conversion of the touch location to the
>   coordinate system of the specified view.

```
    - (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        if([event type] == UIEventTypeTouches)
        {
            NSSet<UITouch *> *allTouches = [event allTouches];
            if(allTouches)
            {
                for(UITouch* touch in allTouches)
                {
                    if([touch type] == UITouchTypeDirect)
                    {
                         // This is 640x1136
                         CGRect bounds = [myWindow bounds];

                         // This is in [318x560] empirically 
                         CGPoint origin = [touch locationInView:myWindow];
                    }
                }    
            }    
        }
    }
```

Can anyone explain?

From questions:

1. Testing on a physical iPhone 6 device.
2. myWindow is the application's main window. Created with `myWindow = [[myWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeBounds]];` during `application: application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions`
3. myWindow has no subviews. Only a `CAEAGLLayer` layer

Comment: Don't use the window, use your root controller's root view.

Comment: @jcaron See the documentation. Window is fine. In fact, passing nil defaults to the Window. I have no subviews.

Comment: What is myWindow? Is it main application's window? How it is created?

Comment: @DisableR Yes, it is the application's main window. Created with `myWindow = [[myWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeBounds]];` during `application: application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each view has a contentScaleFactor property. It is intended to simplify work with different device resolutions (e.g. retina (@2x), non-retina (@1x), @3x, etc.)
`UIWindow` is a subclass of `UIView` so it also has it.

> The scale factor determines how content in the view is mapped from the
>   logical coordinate space (measured in points) to the device coordinate
>   space (measured in pixels). This value is typically either 1.0 or 2.0.
>   Higher scale factors indicate that each point in the view is
>   represented by more than one pixel in the underlying layer. For
>   example, if the scale factor is 2.0 and the view frame size is 50 x 50
>   points, the size of the bitmap used to present that content is 100 x
>   100 pixels.
>
> The default value for this property is the scale factor associated
>   with the screen currently displaying the view. If your custom view
>   implements a custom drawRect: method and is associated with a window,
>   or if you use the GLKView class to draw OpenGL ES content, your view
>   draws at the full resolution of the screen. For system views, the
>   value of this property may be 1.0 even on high resolution screens.

So in your case `[myWindow bounds]` returns logical size equal to device screen size, because you set it to native bounds. Your window is twice bigger than your screen in device coordinates computed from its logical coordinates according to its scale factor (which is equal to 2), and your touches hit only fourth part of it.

```
myWindow = [[myWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
myWindow.layer.contentsScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeScale];

CGPoint origin = [touch locationInView:myWindow];
origin.x *= [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
origin.y *= [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
```

Comment: Can't do that. I use `[myEAGLContext renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:myCAEAGLLayer];`. As such, the view myCAEAGLLayer is attached to has to be set with the correct physical device size - else, as noted in your documentation, the framebuffer allocated by OpenGLES will only be a 4th of what I want.

Comment: Your myCAEAGLLayer and its framebuffers will have a real device size if you set contentScaleFactor to 1.0. GLES will render the window twice bigger than its bounds are.

Comment: Your myCAEAGLLayer should also have contentsScale equal to 1.0. Check CALayer class reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/contentsScale

Comment: Well, after your suggestions, and keeping `[myCAEAGLLayer setContentsScale:[[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeScale]];`, it seems GLES is still allocating a 640x1136 frame buffer (good) - and the touch/window coordinates seem to be consistent (good). I'm not sure if I'm convinced that this is correct though..

Comment: If i just set contentScaleFactor to 1.0 - it results in the same behavior as I had before :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104355/discussion-between-disabler-and-jammie).